# Animation to changing HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, animation, google-photos

I've been trying, for a few days, to add an animation between two ***different*** HTML pages/files (`index.html -> about.html`). My idea is to animate/have a transition when going from one page to the other: in my case from the `index.html` to the `about.html` page.

I found a lot of answers on Google and on StackOverflow, but the problem is that the transition happens ***on the same page*** which means that the `HTML` code for both pages is in the same file and my index.html becomes ***unreadable***, especially if I am working on a project that's quite big.

I saw that Google Photos had something quite similar to what I want to achieve. Just [open Google Photos](https://photos.google.com/) and click on an image, and as you might notice, the URL ***changes*** from `https://photos.google.com` to `https://photos.google.com/photo/PHOTO_ID` and an animation occurs.

Any idea on how Google does this or how **I can do it**? :)
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The solutions I'd rather avoid are:

- AJAX (but it's ok if Google uses it, and I doubt they do)
- Having the `HTML` for both pages in a single, one file.
- AngularJS (I'd prefer pure JS)

( this isn't a duplicate, I'd like to know how Google did it ;) )

Comment: use History API to change the URL without refresh, and use ajax GET or fetch GET to retrieve the content.

Comment: Do you think that it's done this way with Google? I would rather keep my code simple and clean. Any code example? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know how Google does it. I don't know of any other way to change the URL without full page refresh other than use History API. Google seem to use fetch and not ajax.

Comment: I'll look into that. Thanks for the info!

Comment: You may want to research "Angular Single Page Application". This article seems to answer all your questions: https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating

Comment: Yeah that looks Cool! However I'd like to avoid Angular... I'll update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuery to load an HTML file into the body. Here is some *very* untested *pseudo* code to make this boneless, single-page-app work:

**jQuery**

```
//disable link action and load HTML inside the body tag
$('a').on('click', function(){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('body').load($(this).attr('href'));
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <h1>title</h1>
    <a href="about.html">link</a>
</body>
```

If you wish to add an animation effect, you can prepend new HTML to the body, fade the previous HTML, then remove the hidden content.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does the URL change? I would like it to do so

Comment: You can use 'pushState' to change the URL without reloading the page. More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not exactly sure of the method Google uses to achieve this, I do know that many of the solutions you would like to avoid are definitely some of your greater options.

Anyhow, a hack to achieve this would be splitting the code up amongst the two pages. Set up a fade out/any animation after a link is clicked on one page and make the other page fade in/any animation after load on the destination page. This is somewhat similar to how I would do it using an XML request, it's just a bit out of general practice.

Again this is a very 'hacky' method, but it gets the job done with very minimal JavaScript code, depending on how you go about it.

Comment: I see what you mean, and I have already thought about this but: 1- when you open the link with the PHOTO_ID, there is no animation. 2- Usually when you switch pages, you see a blank page when loading the second one. Would you mind giving some code example (jsfiddle, etc..)? Thank you!!